# how to add elements to a list in python

Tags: python

I have a function the encrypt and decrypt a message I want my function to display the answer as such: ['DHBK', 'VZVP'] but right now this is how it is displaying the result: ['D', 'H', 'B', 'K', 'V', 'Z', 'V', 'P'] how can I change my program so it doesn't do that. Right now this is how I'm adding to the list

```
for message in messages:
    message = process_message(deck, message, encrypt_decrypt)
    new_messages += message
return new_messages
```

Comment: It seems your `process_message` is returning individual letters. If you want your lungs diagnosed, you're going to have to show us more than an ankle :P

Comment: Please show a more complete [MCVE] :). We want to help you, but we need to see more of your problem. Show what `process_message` is actually doing, so we know what is being returned by it.

Comment: i think the problem is how I'm adding to the list because when I return message is returns is like this: 'VZVP' so that part is correct but why is this part  (new_messages += message) adding the characters indrividually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + (and by extension +=) operators joins sequences. A string is a sequence, leading to this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> l += s
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

You likely want the append method instead:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> l.append(s)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 'abc']
```

PS. If instead you actually wanted the original result, using the 'extend' method of the string would have been clearer. If instead you were going to join some strings you can avoid confusion caused by using + for joining by using string formatting instead.

Comment: BTW, it might be my personal taste, but I really wouldn't recommend using `+` with lists. It's the same as `append` plus `extend`, except it's more confusing.

Comment: I agree, and I think it applies to joining strings as well. Added a PS.